# Multi-threaded Java TCP Client

Tags: java, multithreading, tcpclient

I am writing a Java client application(Basic Java Net package with TCP/IP). The client must take input from the system.in and at the same time must listen to any messages coming from server through socket inputstream. 
Once an input from the system.in is received, the client will get that input, do some processing and send it to the server as a request.
So basically 2 processes run,

-listening to client request

-listning to server responses.

I implemented 2 threads for this and ran the processing of messages in the main thread.
Is this good enough design.?

And is there a way to return the message received from the system.in to the main thread. The threads run() method returns void. I used a volatile variable to return the string received but its said that volatile is very costly since it doesn't use cpu cache to store the variable.

Comment: Why? You only need to fetch a response after you send a request. You don't need two threads for that.

Comment: Its required for the server to send some definitions upon connection, so the client has to be listening for that and he also have to listen for the requests from the system.in at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can review these two projects I've written for an example of java sockets and multithreading.

- [Client](https://github.com/kaleksandrov/tu-sofia-pik3/tree/master/ClientExample)
- [Server](https://github.com/kaleksandrov/tu-sofia-pik3/tree/master/ServerExample)

I guess the **ClientExample** is the one you are searcing for but you can take a look at the server part too.

Basically the idea is to start two separate threads that listen for the different inputs - socket and console.

```
final Thread outThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Started...");
        PrintWriter out = null;
        Scanner sysIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.println(name);
            out.flush();

            while (sysIn.hasNext() && !isFinished.get()) {
                String line = sysIn.nextLine();
                if ("exit".equals(line)) {
                    synchronized (isFinished) {
                        isFinished.set(true);
                    }
                }
                out.println(line);
                out.flush();
                disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    };
};
outThread.start();
```

and another thread for the socket input:

```
        final Thread inThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Use a Scanner to read from the remote server

                Scanner in = null;
                try {
                    in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    String line = in.nextLine();
                    while (!isFinished.get()) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line = in.nextLine();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        in.close();
                    }
                }
            };
        };
        inThread.start();
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: That was very helpful! But I have to pass the console input to the main thread before writing it to the socket out. Is there a way to return the sysIn to the main thread?

Comment: Is it necessary to process the input in the main thread? Can't you call the processing method in the background thread?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,But if the processing of the thread takes time. It will be no use in using multiple threads right? The thread will be blocked in processing the system.in.

Comment: If the processing takes time, you have to spawn a new thread (or use a ```ThreadPool```) that will process the data and then send it. So it will be something like this: main thread spawns two new threads that reads from the system input and the socket. And the thread that reads the system input spawns a new thread for each new data that will process it. After the processing is done, this thread is responsible to send it to the server. Another approach is to use a queue that will keep the processed data and another thread that reads the queue and sends the data to the server.

Comment: This becomes a lot more complex. I'll advise you to split all this stuff in separate questions.

Comment: That sounds like the best solution for this scenario. Thanks a lot!